Azure Function Automation Stops After Pull Request Is Merged
I'm new to Azure Functions.
We have an automation that runs 22 hours a day with a 2 hour break in order to prevent the temp files from taking up all the storage space on the app host and preventing it from running (according to notes from the dev that built it.)
We recently merged a large pull request. Ever since, our automation stops within a short window of time after a new PR is merge (PRs merge as soon as they are completed.) Copy of a some of the trace included below as an example.
TRACE
Information
Trace Properties
Show all
Event time  4/11/2024, 12:22:35.3071486 PM (Local time)
Device type PC
Message Job host stopped
Severity level  Information
Custom Properties
LogLevel    Information
Category    Host.Startup
prop__{OriginalFormat}  Job host stopped
I've tried looking up our capacity to see if we are possibly running out of temp storage with this most recent PR.
I am not sure I'm looking in the right place. From what I can tell, we are using slightly more storage than before but appear to have plenty of room left. I'm not sure if I am viewing temp storage, though?
We have reviewed the PR for possible conflicts but there's been nothing striking. No one here is an Azure expert, so it's difficult to diagnose. Looking for some ideas. I feel like the temp storage issue could make sense but I'm not sure how to properly diagnose that.

To properly diagnose the issue, you can try to narrow the scope of your troubleshooting to temporary storage by following the steps outlined in this article: "How to troubleshoot temporary storage on Azure App Service" (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/troubleshoot/azure/app-service/temporary-storage-for-azure-app-service#how-to-troubleshoot-temporary-storage-on-azure-app-service). This article provides instructions on how to investigate and troubleshoot performance issues related to temporary storage.
